# Multiple level of inheritance in EF Code First Configuration

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have an abstract base class for a few entities I'm defining. One of those derived entities is actually a non-abstract base class to another entity.

Following this code:

```
public abstract class BaseReportEntry {
      public int ReportEntryId { get; set;}
      public int ReportBundleId { get; set; }  //FK
      public virtual ReportBundle ReportBunde { get; set; } 
}

//A few different simple pocos like this one
public PerformanceReportEntry : BaseReportEntry {
     public int PerformanceAbsolute { get; set; }
     public double PerformanceRelative { get; set; }

}

//And one with a second level of inheritance 
public ByPeriodPerformanceReportEntry : PerformanceReportEntry {
       public string Period { get; set; }
}
```

I'm using a base `EntityTypeConfiguration`:

```
public class BaseReportEntryMap<TReportEntry> : EntityTypeConfiguration<TReportEntry>
    where TReportEntry : BaseReportEntry
{
    public BaseReportEntryMap()
    {
        this.HasKey(e => e.ReportEntryId);

        this.HasRequired(e => e.ReportsBundle)
            .WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey(e => e.ReportsBundleId);
    }
}
```

Presumably this works fine for the one-level of inheritance but throw the following error for that one case where it has a second level:

```
The foreign key component 'ReportsBundleId' is not a declared property on type 'ByPeriodPerformanceReportEntry'


public class ByPeriodPerformanceReportEntryMap : BaseReportEntryMap<ByPeriodPerformanceReportEntry>
{
    public ByPeriodPerformanceReportEntryMap ()
        : base()
    {
        this.Property(e => e.Period).IsRequired();

        this.Map(m =>
        {
            m.MapInheritedProperties();
            m.ToTable("ByPeriodPerformanceReportEntries"); 
        });
    }
}
```

Here's ReportBundle class if needed

```
 public class ReportsBundle 
{
    public int ReportsBundleId { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<PerformanceReportEntry> PerformanceReportEntries{ get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ByPeriodPerformanceReportEntry> ByPeriodPerformanceReportEntries{ get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not so much the second level of inheritance but that `PerformanceReportEntry` (the base of `ByPeriodPerformanceReportEntry`) is an entity while `BaseReportEntry` (the base of `PerformanceReportEntry`) is not.

Your mapping would work if `PerformanceReportEntry` would not be an entity - i.e. its mapping is not added to the model builder configuration and you have no `DbSet` for this type and it would not occur in a navigation collection in `ReportsBundle`.

Deriving the configuration from `BaseReportEntryMap<ByPeriodPerformanceReportEntry>` is not possible in this case - and it is not necessary because the mapping for the base properties already happened by the `BaseReportEntryMap<PerformanceReportEntry>`. Therefore you can use

```
public class ByPeriodPerformanceReportEntryMap
    : EntityTypeConfiguration<ByPeriodPerformanceReportEntry>
```

But I have doubt that the resulting model is as you would expect it. I don't know what the `PerformanceReportEntries` and `ByPeriodPerformanceReportEntries` collections in `ReportsBundle` are supposed to express. Do you expect that `ByPeriodPerformanceReportEntries` is a collection filtered by the subtype? Do you expect that `PerformanceReportEntries` contains only the ReportsEntries that are `PerformanceReportEntry`s but not `ByPeriodPerformanceReportEntry`s? Do you expect that `PerformanceReportEntries` contains all entries including the `ByPeriodPerformanceReportEntries`?

Anyway, `BaseReportEntry.ReportBundle` is a navigation property mapped in `PerformanceReportEntry` (not in `ByPeriodPerformanceReportEntry`). That means that the inverse navigation property in class `ReportsBundle` must refer to `PerformanceReportEntry` which is the `PerformanceReportEntries` navigation collection. `ByPeriodPerformanceReportEntries` will introduce a second one-to-many relationship between `ReportsBundle` and `ByPeriodPerformanceReportEntry` (without a navigation property in `ByPeriodPerformanceReportEntry`). The inverse navigation property of `ByPeriodPerformanceReportEntries` will NOT be `BaseReportEntry.ReportBundle`.

My feeling is that you should not have the `ReportsBundle.ByPeriodPerformanceReportEntries` collection, but I am not sure what you want to achieve exactly.

**Edit**

Refering to your comment that you only have these two Report types your mapping is way too complicated in my opinion. I would do the following:

- Remove the `BaseReportEntry` class and move its properties into `PerformanceReportEntry`. It makes no sense to have a base class that only one single other class derives from.
- Remove the `ByPeriodPerformanceReportEntries` from `ReportsBundle`, so that `ReportsBundle` will be:

  ```
  public class ReportsBundle 
  {
      public int ReportsBundleId { get; set; }
      public virtual ICollection<PerformanceReportEntry>
          PerformanceReportEntries { get; set; }
  }
  ```
- Remove the `BaseReportEntryMap` and move the mapping into `PerformanceReportEntryMap`. Derive this map from `EntityTypeConfiguration<PerformanceReportEntry>`.
- Correct the mapping. Currently it is wrong because you don't specify the inverse navigation property in `WithMany`. `PerformanceReportEntryMap` should look like this:

  ```
  public class PerformanceReportEntryMap
      : EntityTypeConfiguration<PerformanceReportEntry>
  {
      public PerformanceReportEntryMap()
      {
          this.HasKey(e => e.ReportEntryId);

          this.HasRequired(e => e.ReportsBundle)
              .WithMany(b => b.PerformanceReportEntries)
              .HasForeignKey(e => e.ReportsBundleId);
      }
  }
  ```
- Derive `ByPeriodPerformanceReportEntryMap` from `EntityTypeConfiguration<ByPeriodPerformanceReportEntry>` and specify only mappings for properties that are *declared* in `ByPeriodPerformanceReportEntry`, not again for the base properties. That already happened in `PerformanceReportEntryMap`. You don't need and can't specify it again because it will cause exactly the exception you had.
- Use Table-Per-Hierarchy (TPH) inheritance instead of Table-Per-Concrete-Type (TPC), especially if you only have a few properties declared in `ByPeriodPerformanceReportEntry`. TPC is more difficult to use because it has problems with database-generated identities and with polymorphic associations (which you have in your relationship between `PerformanceReportEntry` and `ReportsBundle`). [The problems are explained in more details here](http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/archive/2011/01/03/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-3-table-per-concrete-type-tpc-and-choosing-strategy-guidelines.aspx). TPH instead offers the best performance. `ByPeriodPerformanceReportEntryMap` would then look like this:

  ```
  public class ByPeriodPerformanceReportEntryMap
      : EntityTypeConfiguration<ByPeriodPerformanceReportEntry>
  {
      public ByPeriodPerformanceReportEntryMap()
      {
          this.Property(e => e.Period).IsRequired();
      }
  }
  ```

  No explicit configuration for TPH is necessary because it is the default inheritance mapping.

Comment: Thanks for the reply and sorry for the lack of clarity. Basically I'm modeling an external reporting system that has these 2 separate reports. I intended to use ByPeriodPerformanceReportEntry and PerformanceReportEntry them as separate concrete entities that basically just have common properties (PerformanceAbsolute, PerformanceAbsolute, many more). Do you think you can update your code with maps using this new information? Thank you for the helps

Comment: I think perhaps you mean something along making PerformanceReportEntry abstract and create a 3rd class like "ConsolidatedPerformanceReportEntry" for the concrete implementation. Will that work? Is it the best option?

Comment: @Vazgen: I have added an Edit section to my answer.

Comment: I didnt say these were the ONLY reports I'm mapping, just 2 of them. Regardless I gleamed enough from your answer in partciular about specifying the inverse navigation property to fix up my example. Thanks, much appreciated

Comment: @Vazgen: Sorry, then I misunderstood your comment. If you have other reports deriving directly from `BaseReportEntry`, then of course I would keep this class and create an `ICollection<BaseReportEntry>` in `ReportsBundle` (instead of the `PerformanceReportEntries`). But still don't derive the other mappings from `BaseReportEntryMap<T>`, just from `EntityTypeConfiguration<T>`.